# PHPMyAdmin like interface for Apache Solr?

Tags: user-interface, search-engines

I would like to view the contents in my Apache Solr installation like phpmyadmin shows sql tables. Are you aware of any? Mongodb has rockmongo, hbase has https://github.com/hivefans/phphbaseadmin  for example, so I am hoping we have sg similar for Apache Solr as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not built with php, but there is the solar admin ui https://home.apache.org/~ctargett/RefGuidePOC/jekyll-full/overview-of-the-solr-admin-ui.html